# How to copy data from an array to an apex heatmap chart?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I created a apex heatmap chart and added the following state data to fill the diagram with initial values.

```
    this.state = {   
        seriesCompact: [{
            name: '1',
            data: [45, 123, 4864, 1531, 121, 15]
            },
            {
                name: '2',
                data: [534, 4534, 12, 784, 121, 8847]
            },
            {
                name: '3',
                data: [453, 453, 12, 453, 135, 51]
            },
            {
                name: '4',
                data: [4, 453, 45, 12, 44, 153]
            },
            {
                name: '5',
                data: [51, 513, 45, 12, 84, 21]
            },
            {
                name: '6',
                data: [434, 453, 8464, 534, 87643, 543]
            },
        ],
    }
```

I fetched data from the database and stored it in an array. It contains 36 integer values.

```
let data = [543,220195,56767,578433,45773,573335,501974,846359,88518,673208,
10086,705133,332856,449014,167144,102293,241678,661375,322747,830976,841206,254525,         17574,80045,717178,290102,59301,368118,
852860,246908,453454,601215,640807,530396,219809,986924];
```

I want to replace the data from the 6 data fields above with the values from the array.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your array, can you show what you have done so far. Add little more details

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help :

```js
for(let serie of state.seriesCompact){
    serie.data=data; 
    num=num+6;
}
//Result:
console.log(state.seriesCompact);
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the structure of your data. I'll assume that your data is sequential in groups of 6 (6 per series). If you provide more details, I can update my answer.

```js
const updateSeriesData = data => {
  // get the current series
  let { seriesCompact } = this.state;

  // move through data array and assign `seriesCompact[i].data` a new six values
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    // slice the data beginning at 
    // (6 * i) and ending at (6 * (i + 1)) noninclusive
    seriesCompact[i].data = data.slice(6 * i, 6 * (i + 1));
  }

  // set state with new series
  this.setState({ seriesCompact });
}
```